# Searching GMail messages via IMAP

Tags: java, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am using JavaMail to find specific messages. The messages of my interest would be all those messages which have specific "TO" field.

Let me explain more.

Lets assume that my email account is `email@gmail.com`. I will be expecting emails sent to `email+label@gmail.com`. I want to search all those emails which are sent **TO** `email+label@gmail.com`.

Is it supported by IMAP ?

---

I found this code for searching gmail, I am not sure if its supported by JavaMail or not (can't test it here behind firwall atm). So can someone explain what does this code means?

`['X-GM-RAW has:attachment']`

if its the same thing which i am guessing i.e. **has:attachment** is the query that we use in gmail search then i guess i can replace it with **to:email+label@gmail.com**

Comment: I believe ih ave found the answer http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/#x-gm-raw

Answer (score 0):

It's supported by [IMAP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol#Server-side_searches), not by previous versions I believe. 
Not sure what version GMail is supporting right now.